# Kotlin generic type inference - inheritance

Tags: kotlin, generics, inheritance, abstraction

I have some abstract with generic type:

```
interface Abstract<T> {
    val dataHolder: T
}

class AbstractImplA : Abstract<String> { 
    override val dataHolder = "Test"
}

class AbstractImplB : Abstract<Int> {
    override val dataHolder = 1
}
```

Now I want to create `open` class that persist this data:

```
open class Base<T>(private val abstract: Abstract<T>) {

    val data : T get() = abstract.dataHolder

    // ...
}
```

now for child class I have to explicitly specifiy generic type of Abstract:

```
class ClassA : Base<String>(AbstractImplA()) {

    fun foo() {
        assertEquals("Test", data)
    }
}

class ClassB : Base<Int>(AbstractImplB()) {

    fun foo() {
        assertEquals(1, data)
    }
}
```

I wander if Kotlin can infere this type.

Passing wrong generic type causes `Type mismatch` error ex. `class ClassB : Base<Boolean>(AbstractImplB())`

Can I somehow write it like this?:

```
class ClassB : Base(AbstractImplB()) {

    fun foo() {
        assertEquals(1, data)
    }
}
```